# Decide Refractive index of a unknown piece of glass

Tags: experimental-physics, software, data-analysis

## Problem:

The task is to find $n_2$ by Fresnel's equation from given data.

## My attempt at solution:

I begin from this equation:

$$R= \left|\frac{(n_2\cos\theta_i - n_1\cos\theta_t)}{(n_2\cos\theta_i + n_1\cos\theta_t)}\right|$$

The index of refraction of:

$$n_1 = 1$$

Here is the python code I used to plot $R$ and then I tried to find a good approximated value of $n_2$ which is $n_2=2.21\;$

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import pylab as cbt
import scipy.linalg as alxx


def func(angleIncident):  
n1=1
n2=2.21

angleRad = (np.pi*(angleIncident/180)) #degree to rad
part1 = (n1*np.sqrt(1-((n1/n2) * np.sin(angleRad)**2)))
part2= (n2*np.cos(angleRad))

return ((np.abs((part1-part2)/(part1+part2)))**2)*(1000)
```

[image: my plot looked like this..]

I'm not sure if I used the "$R$" function correctly in my python code and for some reason I have to multiply the whole function in my python code with 1000 or else it's way out of scale and I got no clue why?

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is? Is your question "why do I have to multiply by 1000"?

Comment: @Brionius Sorry if it's messy. That's one of my questions and if I rewrote the $R_p$ function correctly, like does the graph make sence or is something wrong?

Comment: @`Jenna9`: It is not clear whether you are asking for a correct code or a physical problem. In the former case, the proper place would be `stackoverflow.com`. In the latter case, you have to clarify the _physical_ question.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not given the input power, there will be an arbitrary scaling factor (your Fresnel equations give power reflection coefficient - multiply by incident power to get reflected power)

Second, you do not specify whether this light is polarized. The equation used changes depending on the polarization; and from the slightly poor for I wonder whether you might in fact have the wrong equation (wrong model)

With that said, the minimum in the power curve should occur close to the Brewster angle - from which the refractive index would follow.

Incidentally - it may be necessary to consider the reflection at the second surface assuming this is a transparent piece of glass - it is not sufficient to look just at the primary surface (unless the glass is very thick and the beam well collimated so you are sure you are looking only at the reflection from the primary air/glass interface).

I have answered a related question before... You might find [the answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/174949/26969) useful.

Comment: Why would the model for the reflection be wrong?

Comment: @Jenna9 I said it might be wrong if (a) the polarization wasn't properly taken into account (you had not specified in the question but confirm that it is an incident p polarization), or if you needed to account for reflection off the back surface (depends on collimation). Given the divergence of data and model at grazing incidence I do wonder...